# how do I recreate my ubuntu account?

Tags: lightdm

I ran `sudo apt-get remove wine*` and it removed my account. When I try to log in a nivida screen flashes (that's normal) and then I'm back at the log in screen. What can I do? I have files that I don't want to waste, I could get them bakup if I could log into the computer. Well wine is gone so the command worked in a way ( What did it do?).

can I create a new admin with the usb or a new account? it's really annoying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that ubuntu-desktop & other important packages (gnome-applets, gnome-session) would get removed by removing wine that way.

To reinstall them from a terminal, run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: I will install unity when it's realesed so if not all programs were installed again that were removed. but it worked, wine is gone!

Answer (score 0):

Your account probably hasn't been removed.

You could try using a virtual console and logging in to your account that way, instead of through a GUI. Use [CTRL][ALT][F1] and enter your username and password. You should be able to look through your files as normal, through the command line.

If you have to do some major surgery, you should be able to copy your documents to a safe place, then clean out your /home/yourusername folder, then copy back the contents of /etc/skel to /home/yourusername, and copy back your documents.